# How to get number at decimal position

Tags: c, gps, can-bus

I am working on C code for microcontroller to format GPS data into one 8 byte message.

I need to code it and decode fast.
I want to do it like that:
Int32 is -2147483648 to 2147483647.

We can code Latitude:
-89599999 to -89599999 what is position 89° 59.9999’ S  to 90° 59.9999’ N
For Longitude:
-179599999 to 179599999 what is position 179° 59.9999’ W to 179° 59.9999’ E

4 bytes for Latitude and 4 bytes for Longitude.  In total 8 bytes CAN message.

How to do it without multiply and divide?  Is there wny way to shift or get number at wanted
decimal position.

I want to code in the way:

```
unsigned int32 charToInt32(char val)
{
   unsigned int32 valOut;
   valOut = val - '0';
   return valOut;
}

int32 GPS_codeLongitude(char *tab, char dir)
{
   int32 deg = 0;  

   deg  = charToInt32(tab[0]) * 1000000000; 
   deg += charToInt32(tab[1]) * 100000000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[2]) * 10000000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[3]) * 1000000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[4]) * 100000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[6]) * 10000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[7]) * 1000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[8]) * 100;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[9]) * 10; 
   deg += charToInt32(tab[10]); 

   if(dir == 'S') deg = -deg;
   return deg;
}

int32 GPS_codeLatitude(char *tab, char dir)
{
   int32 deg = 0;  

   deg  = charToInt32(tab[0]) * 100000000; 
   deg += charToInt32(tab[1]) * 10000000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[2]) * 1000000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[3]) * 100000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[5]) * 10000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[6]) * 1000;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[7]) * 100;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[8]) * 10;
   deg += charToInt32(tab[9]) ; 

   if(dir == 'W') deg = -deg;
   return deg;
}
```

Comment: How do you know whether `179599999` represents `17.9599999` or `179.599999`? Why not use two `float` values? You can't store 10 decimal digits precisely in 32 bits, as your code is attempting.

Comment: Are your input data like `char tab[] = "179599999";` for 179°59.9999'? Did you try `atoi()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: 179599999 is nine digits, not ten. Even if it were ten (another 9 were appended), it fits in 32 bits, even with a sign bit. And `float` is not appropriate for this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil please read the posted code carefully from line 11 to line 20.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Ah, you are right, the code does not match the question text. Nonetheless, 1,795,999,999 fits in 31 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I *do* agree that the question is not very clear.

Comment: How do you get the GPS data? Can you provide or link the data format specification? What GPS receiver do you use? Can it be switched to sending binary data instead of text format? Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: The question is incorrectly and poorly written. The code mixes up latitude and longitude: Longitude is east/west, but `codeLongitude` checks for `'S'` , and latitude is north/south, but `codeLatitude` checks for `'W'`. The question text shows nine digits for longitude (179 59 9999), but `codeLongitude` uses ten digits. In any case, it is not feasible to encode and decode decimal digits without using multiplication and division. If there were a little more room, binary-coded decimal could be used with just shifts and masks, but even nine digits is too much for that, let alone ten.

Comment: "For Longitude: -179599999 to 179599999 what is position 179° 59.9999’ W to 179° 59.9999’ E" omits the possibility of being at 180°E (or W)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
static void int2str(char *buf, unsigned int x)
{
    const unsigned int divs[] = { 1000000000, 100000000, 10000000, 1000000,
     100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof divs / sizeof *divs; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char digit = '0';
        while (x >= divs[i])
        {
            ++digit;
            x -= divs[i];
        }
        *buf++ = digit;
    }
    *buf++ = '0' + x;
    *buf = '\0';
}
```

This will zero-pad to the left, but that's usually okay for computer-to-computer talk. Also, it doesn't use any multiplications or divisions, but it's very iterative so not exactly fast ...

Answer (score 0):

Example with usage of atoi and bitwise operations:

```
#define CanMessageLen 8
#define NIBBLELEN 4
typedef char CanMessage[CanMessageLen];


typedef enum
{
    NORTH,
    SOUTH
} LatitudeDir;

typedef enum
{
    EAST,
    WEST
} LongitudeDir;

CanMessage* CoordinatesToMsg(char* latitude, LatitudeDir latitudedir, char* longitude , LongitudeDir longitudedir)
{
    CanMessage canMessage = { 0 };
    __int32 latitudeInt=0;
    __int32 longitudeInt = 0;

    latitudeInt = atoi(latitude);
    longitudeInt = atoi(longitude);

    if (latitudedir == SOUTH)
    {
        latitudeInt = -latitudeInt;
    }
    if (longitudedir == WEST)
    {
        longitudeInt = -longitudeInt;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        canMessage[i] = (char)(latitudeInt >> (8 * i) & 0xff);
        canMessage[i+4] = (char)(longitudeInt >> (8 * i) & 0xff);
    }
    return canMessage;
}
```

Example -80° 55.9999'  150° 55.9999

```
char latitude[10] = { '0','8','0','5','5','9','9','9','9','\0'}; 
char longitude[10] = { '1','5','0','5','5','9','9','9','9','\0'}; 

CoordinatesToMsg(latitude, SOUTH,longitude, EAST);
```

Output [0x81,0xC0,0x32, 0xFB, 0xFF, 0x5C, 0xF9, 0x08] //Little Endian